# iPhone - crazy timestamp

Tags: iphone

I have this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

after running this date is equal to

> 2010-11-05 21:45:56 GMT

and timeStamp is equal to

> 2010-**45**-05T21:45:56.46700

month = 45 ???????????????????????????

any solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mm is for minutes. You want MM for months.

iPhone uses the [Unicode Standards](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for date formatting. MM will give you the number of the month, prefixing 0 if necessary to have 2 digits, M will give you the number of the month without the leading 0.